# how to show that the group $(G,+)$ is abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, binary-operations

How to show that the group $(G,+)$ is abelian and I already proved  that $(0,0)$ is a neutral element of  addition   and this is the givings $G=\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Z}$ with operations 
$(a,b)+(c,b)=(a+c , b+d)$

Comment: A group that has "both addition and multiplication"?

Comment: I've edited the text to make it more readible. Please check whether everything is still all right

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! That's fine,but *what*  is $G$?

Comment: the name of the group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both factors in the direct product are abelian, so is the direct product. Indeed

$$(a,b) + (c,d) = (a+c,b+d) = (c+a,b+d) = (c,d) + (a,b)$$

Comment: but shouldn't i use arbitrary values for a,b,c and d to prove it

Comment: @HazemJardaly a,b,c,d are already assumed to be arbitrary